# How to use a compiled ES6 to ES5 file in browser?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two modules in ES6:

```
//mycalss.js
class MyClass {
}
export {MyClass};

//main.js
import {MyClass} from './../src/myclass';
```

And I am using Laravel-mix to handle the compilation and bundle process.

In the end I end up with a `main.js`.

I link this file in my html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

And try to make a reference to the class `MyClass`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var object = new MyClass();

</script>
```

But a `Uncaught ReferenceError: MyClass is not defined` is thrown.

So, how do I use a classe compiled from es6 to es5 in my html?

Comment: You can't. The "bundled" JS files are likely to be within a function scope and will not likely expose the variables/objects.

Comment: Perhaps you can explicitly expose the objects you want to reuse? In `main.js` you would do something like `window.MyClass = MyClass`, and then it would be visible to any other script that is not part of your bundle (of course that's assuming you really need to do that in the first place...)

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't. The code that uses MyClass should be inside main.js, not in inline script. This is the purpose of ES6 modules.

Comment: @evolutionxbox You are right. After checking the compiled file I noticed that the class declaration is inside a function scope.

Comment: @HuguesMoreau I used `window.MyClass = Myclass` and it worked as intended. I know this is not recomended, but I need to used the compiled file in a inline script. Thanks!

Comment: @estus I got your point. What do you recommend in a case where I need to use the compiled js file in a inline script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 modules have module scope. This prevents them from leaking variables to global scope. This is exactly what modularity is for.

In order to use items from ES6 modules (the same applies to CommonJS modules or IIFEs that implement module pattern) in global scope, they have to be defined as globals. In the case of client-side script this means that they should be defined as `window` properties inside bundled application:

```
window.MyClass = MyClass;
```

This indicates potential XY problem. A better option is to reconsider the reasons why it should be available in global scope. If there is bundled ES6 application already, it is supposed to run code from inline `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>` too.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Babel](https://babeljs.io) to compile JavaScript from ES6 to ES5 in browser.

Often, you have to use [webpack](https://webpack.github.io) to do that automatically for you and insert the script inside HTML.